# Find installed package with expect on linux

Tags: expect

I would like to check if an rpm package installed on the server and the version of that.

```
send "rpm -qa | grep ^cman\r"
expect {
  -re "(cman-.*)\r" { set cman $expect_out(0,string) }
  default { set cman "no cman" }
}
```

It works correctly when cman installed, but waiting with timeout when cman isn't on the list.

How should I check the else thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
send "rpm -qa | grep ^cman || echo 'c'man_not_found\r"
expect {
  -re "(cman-.*)\r" {
    set cman $expect_out(1,string)
  }
  cman_not_found {
    set cman "no cman"
  }
}
```

Comment: The main lesson I learnt from this: Error should never pass silently. Thanks